# Prevent Embedded Youtube video from being paused?

Tags: jquery, youtube

I am embedding a youtube video in a site and would like to prevent the ability to click on it (which pauses the video). Have tried various things using jQuery, like stopPropagation, preventDefault, etc.

In a nutshell, I want to add something so that clicking on the page does absolutely nothing. Would appreciate any ideas thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the YouTube chromeless player and control the player with [the JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

Comment: Not sure if that solves my problem... even with the JSAPI, I wouldn't know what event to intercept.

Comment: @R.K.: The chromeless player doesn't handle clicks at all.